# C# dll which is inter-operable with php and java

Tags: c#, java, php, dll, language-interoperability

I need to create a dll in C sharp which is interoperable with php and Tomcat/Java webservices.

Will the normal C# class library help me for this?

Thanks,
John

Comment: What's the point anyway?

Comment: Are you *producing* or *consuming* the web service?

Answer (score 0):

> Will the normal C# class library help me for this?

You could expose the class library as [WCF service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx) using the interoperable [basicHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731134.aspx) which could be consumed by PHP and Java.

Answer (score 0):

I'm interpreting that as "I need to consume a web-service", in which case either use wsdl.exe, or use the "Add Web Reference..." / "Add Service Reference..." option in Visual Studio. Either approach results in appropriate proxy classes being created that represent the target service's WSDL.

This is *data/protocol* interoperability; note that the dll *itself* won't be directly usable from java / php.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear on which way to "operability" goes. I assume you are talking about making a C# class library that will *call* these web services, which happens to be implemented in PHP/TomCat/Java.

And yes, the .Net Framework have excellent support for calling http endpoints. Also, if these endpoints happen to return XML data, there is excellent support for working with that too. If the services are RESTful, you even have support for that.

**Update:** since my initial assumption was wrong, and the interoperability must go from PHP/Java to .Net I suggest looking at how these languages can interop with COM. .Net classes can be exposed as COM classes, which further can be consumed by [PHP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnetinterop/archive/2005/05/26/422143.aspx) and [Java](http://sourceforge.net/projects/j-interop/).

Comment: ThanksPeter for you response.I need to call the functions exported from the dll inside a web service.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Im wrong about what is the question, but you can use c# assemblies in php with the DOTNET class:

http://php.net/manual/en/class.dotnet.php